# iOS 14 apps failed on over the air installation

Tags: ios, ios14, failed-installation, over-the-air

I am getting the error 'unable to install app' while installing the app on iOS 14. For other iOS versions 10, 11, 12 and 13 it is working fine. I am using the HTTPS URL for app installation. The app has built with Xcode 12.2. Please help.

Comment: Have you got any solution? Same issue on iOS 14.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue that is very familiar to yours. I build an HTTPS web server with a `self-signed` certificate. I've been using OTA to distribute IPA, until iOS 14.5 and later there was an error when installing apps. After googling a few days, I tried the following, but none of them works for me:

1. Check if the URL in the manifest.plist uses https.
2. Check if the root certificate is trusted in Settings.
3. Upgrade openssl version, Upgrade Apache version to support tls1.3.

Later, I saw an installation failed message in console.app. According to the error message, I know that the problem must be the certificate.

Finally, I solved my issue by recreating a version3(SAN) self-signed certificate.
My Apache version: `Apache/2.4.47 (Unix)`. OpenSSL version: `OpenSSL 1.1.1k`

Here is the command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" \
  -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.net,IP:10.0.0.1"
```

Furthermore, there are lots of ways to create self-signed certificate, however, only this one line command works for OpenSSL ≥ 1.1.1.